Simplicial homotopy
I need to show that for a Kan complex $Y$ simplicial homotopy of maps $X \to Y$ rel $A$ is a equivalence relation.
I found a proof for that in nLab https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+homotopy which I dont quite understand. This is shown there first for $0$ simplicies i.e points. Reflexivity is ok. I understand that a homotopy between two points is equivalent to a 1- simplex (i.e a line) with vertices the two points. So for transitivity suppose that there is a simplex $v_2$ with vertices $x,y$ and $v_0$ with vertices $(y,z)$. I need to show that there is a 1- simplex with vertecies $x,z$. For that nLab claims that we are given a map from the 2-1 horn to $Y$ given by $v_0,v_2$ I dont understand how this map should look like. I mean dont we have given exactly the opposit? we have given a line but the horn is exactly the simplex without that line (we are given), so I dont understand that. Can someone explain me that?
Same problem for symmetry, given a simplex $v_2$ with vertices $x,y$ he claims that defining $v_1 = s_0(x)$ then $(v_1,v_2)$ gives us a map between the 2 0 horn and Y analogly I dont understand why.
Moreover I dont really get how the general case is derived from the case for points. This sounds a bit handwaving in the nLab, is there a more formal way of deducing it?

The Horns have an extremely useful combinatorial description as coequalisers of a certain form. Indeed. If you want to see a proof of this, see e.g. Goerss-Jardine "Simplicial Homotopy Theory", chapter one. But hopefully it is topologically plausible, since if you picture the standard realisation of the horn you see that it is composed of $(n-1)$ simplices suitably glued.
So, if $Q$ is a simplicial set then $\mathsf{sSet}(\Lambda^2_1,Q)$ is in natural bijection with the data of maps $a,b:\Delta^1\to Q$ such that $a\circ\delta_0=b\circ\delta_1:\Delta^0\to Q$, (by my link) or alternatively it is just the data of two edges $a:x\to y$ and $b:y\to z$. Again, picture this topologically; $|\Lambda^2_1|$ is just two lines joined together at a point (a triangle missing one edge), so this makes sense - I hope. nLab is being completely rigorous here (I'll grant you, they aren't always)! Composable paths in $Q$ are exactly the same thing as maps $\Lambda^2_1\to Q$, and that is part of the reason why horns are used to define infinity categories.
So, if $Q$ is Kan (or an infinity category) this horn may be filled and some $\sigma\in Q_2$ exists so that $d_0\sigma=b$ and $d_2\sigma=a$; $d_1\sigma$ will be your required edge $x\to z$, though it is non-unique.
For exactly the same reasons, $\mathsf{sSet}(\Lambda^2_0,Q)$ is in natural bijection with the data of maps $a,b:\Delta^1\to Q$ such that $a\circ\delta_1=b\circ\delta_1$, i.e. two edges which begin at the same point. And, you know, given $v:x\to y$, $s_0(x)$ is another edge beginning at the same point $x$ so $v$, $s_0(x)$ together produce a map $\Lambda^2_0\to Q$ which can be filled by some $\sigma:\Delta^2\to Q$; $e=d_0\sigma$ will be a one simplex necessarily agreeing with $d_1\sigma=s_0(x),d_2\sigma=v$ and it follows $e$ is a path $y\to x$, as desired.
The general case is derived from points just because if $Y$ is Kan then $\mathrm{Fun}(X,Y)$ is Kan (iirc!) and homotopy classes of map $X\to Y$ correspond to points of $\mathrm{Fun}(X,Y)$ modulo the relation of edge-connectivity i.e. homotopies between points. Think, an edge of $\mathrm{Fun}(X,Y)$ is some $\Delta^1\to\mathrm{Fun}(X,Y)$ or, by adjunction, some $\Delta^1\times X\to Y$... a homotopy. If you want more elaboration on that, please say more precisely what is confusing you.
